# Dynamic Linq: How to specify the StringComparison type?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm working on doing some custom filtering and sorting of a dataset, based on a collection of sort fields sent from the client browser, and am using Dynamic Linq to achieve (most of) the desired effect.  Where I'm running into a problem is when I try to sort by a column of type String, which contains both traditional strings and numbers stored as strings.  It doesn't appear that I can pass in a StringComparison enum value, or specify an IComparer parameter for the Dynamic Linq orderby function.

My sorting code looks like:

```
myList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("StringColWithNums ASC")
```

I end up with:

```
1
10
100
11
12
2
20
```

instead of:

```
1
2
10
11
12
20
100
```

Anyone have any experience doing something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not something that can be accomplished out of the box with Dynamic Linq, at least not in .NET 2.0/3.5.  I ended up modifying the Dynamic Linq source code in order to accomplish what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.AsQueryable().Sort((r, s) => int.Parse(r).CompareTo(int.Parse(s)));
```

will take some tweaking if those are objects, just use `int.Parse(r.StringColWithNums)`, or whatever the field is.

Oops, sorry, didn't read all the OP to see it has letters too and you want the dynamic linq, editing

**EDIT**

I don't know that you're going to be able to do that using Dynamic linq and passing IComparer.  You may be able to do it after getting the results (i.e. as I was originally writing the sort, with modifications).  Comment if you want to pursue that line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental problem with attempting to perform numeric comparisons within a string comparison.  A couple of ways I would do this:

- When loading the list, prefix numbers with an amount of zeroes that will accompany the max string size, i.e. `String.Format("000000", number)`.  This will only work if you care mostly about sorting and less about the appearance of the results - even then, you could convert "000010" back to a numeric and call the ToString() method to display the number again without the leading zeroes.
- Write your own implementation (extension method) of OrderBy wherein you pass a function (or anonymous function) as a parameter to re-sort the results calling the method passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by writing a new string comparer

```
 class AlphaNumericComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                // if both values are integers then do int comparision
                int xValue, yValue;
                if (int.TryParse(x, out xValue) && int.TryParse(y, out yValue))
                    return xValue.CompareTo(yValue);

                return x.CompareTo(y); // else do string comparison
            }
        }
```

Then you can use the comparer in methods like OrderBy and Sort

```
var sorted = lst.OrderBy(s => s, new AlphaNumericComparer());

lst.Sort(new AlphaNumericComparer());
```

This will give you the desired result. If not then just tweak the comparer.

Comment: I don't think you can use a string comparer with dynamic linq though, I went down that road and wasn't able to get it to go.

Comment: HI, I tried it on `dynamic linq`, but this is not working.